# How to get max(id) of row data MySql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get the maximum id of row data. In my table first column is id then firstname and etc.
this is the sql command I used to get the max(id) of row data.

```
<?PHP  $maxid=$this->db->query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM `emplyee_personal_details`");
                print_r( $maxid) ;?>
```

but it prints bunch of data as it is a array. But I need only the maximam id of row data for validation before data inserting and updating.

How to get the maxid. I use codeigniter framework.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
$maxid = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(id) AS `maxid` FROM `emplyee_personal_details`')->row()->maxid;
```

UPDATE

This will work even if your table is empty (unlike my example above):

```
$maxid = 0;
$row = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(id) AS `maxid` FROM `emplyee_personal_details`')->row();
if ($row) {
    $maxid = $row->maxid; 
}
```

Comment: I get following erro message, Trying to get property of non-object from CI framework. and can you explain bit your answere.

Comment: That's weird... here's the deal: `row()` grabs the row data object from your query and `maxid` grabs the `MAX(id)` value and assigns it to the `$maxid` variable.

Comment: when I change max to maxid I get follwing error. Undefined property: stdClass::$maxid

Comment: Are you sure you copied it correctly? btw. changing max to maxid was just for your convenience

Comment: Ah, it might be failing if your table is empty... let me update my answer.

Comment: final comment can you tell me where you find maxid grabs the MAX(id). ? Your answere perfectly works for me. I just need how you get that knoweledge.

Comment: I'll write it like this: `$this->db->query('SELECT MAX(id) AS thisone FROM emplyee_personal_details')->row()->thisone;`  Basically, I'm just aliasing MAX(id) for easier reference. So when we get the row object, it contains all the columns we asked for (in this case only MAX(id) aliased as `thisone`); from then, we just select that column. Let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21568/discussion-between-kiriappa-and-shomz)

Answer (score 5):

The problem with using a raw query like "SELECT MAX(id) ..." is it is not abstract and may not work for every SQL engine.  I think the active record way to do it is like this:

```
$this->db->select_max('id');
$query = $this->db->get('emplyee_personal_details');
// Produces: SELECT MAX(id) as age FROM emplyee_personal_details
```

See: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: I want to get the final row of id in order to decide to update or insert data in my application. there may be 10 rows but final id may be 15 since some rows can be deleted.

Comment: Then you want the last inserted id?  Like this? $this->db->insert_id(); See: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html

Comment: He's not inserting anything, but deciding whether to insert or update... which is why that won't work.

Comment: how to put $this->db->select_max('id') in $this->db->where() condition?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

That will get you the highest id value, and when I read this, "it prints bunch of data as it is a array" I get the sense that what you really want is a part of that array.  DB queries always return complex structures like arrays or objects.  So if you wanted just the scalar value (the number as an integer) you might use something like this:

```
$maxid = (int)$maxid['id'];
```

or like this (if you have an object):

```
$maxid = (int)$maxid->id;
```

HTH, ~Ray

Comment: See my comment on Samuel's answer.

Comment: @Kolink: I understand your point and that may be quite true, but as a practical matter, I also understand the following...  the table is probably a list of employees, thus it does not have very many rows.  The difference in elapsed time between any of the query solutions here will be impossibly small, perhaps below the threshold of measurement.  Some things should not be optimized because it takes longer to make the change than all the value the change will ever produce!

Comment: Well, your answer is suggesting they change the whole query. Shomz's answer explains how to use the result of the query they have.

Comment: @Ray Paseur Looking at your Reputation, you may have considered formatting the code in you answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,hope it helps,

```
return $this->db->select_max('id')
                        ->get('your_table_name')
                        ->row()->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getMaxCategoryId() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT category_id+1 AS maxid FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category ORDER BY category_id DESC LIMIT 1");
    return $query->row['maxid'];
}
```

error undefined index maxid

Comment: I have formatted your code however this answer looks a lot like a question with an error message. Please consider the question and frame your answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php`$qry = "select max(ID)+1 As ID from records";`
$result = $con->query($qry);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();`echo "New ID To Enter = ".$row["ID"];?>
```

**After Connection Just Write This Code It Will Work**

Comment: Actually, the `+1` is not needed (it will return the wrong value), and the top answer is much more eloquent.

Comment: Well Bro it gives the Maximum ID to Enter in Record & i think it is much easier than top answers

Comment: Actually, your solution does not give back the highest ID, but highest ID + 1, which is not what was asked. Why would you add 1 to the max ID?